# How do I tell Windows 7 that I don't have a battery backup?

Tags: windows-7, power-management, sleep, battery

One of my computers recently started going to sleep at seemingly random intervals.  Upon examining the system log, the reason is always the same.  "The system is entering sleep.  Sleep Reason: Battery"

This computer doesn't have a battery backup, and there is no third-party power management software installed.  However, Windows thinks there is a battery backup.  It shows a battery icon in the tray that indicates "Fully charged (100%)", and all the power options allow me to specify what to do when on battery and when plugged in.  I have set all those options to never go to sleep, but it doesn't want to listen.  It still goes to sleep sometimes.

My computer at work doesn't give me a choice of what to do when on battery vs. when plugged in, so there must be a way to tell Windows there is no battery backup.  Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: It sounds like this is a laptop. Therefore, it has a battery. In this case, Windows monitors the battery and goes to sleep to conserve power (unless you change it). This is typical behavior. Check your Power Settings. If this is not the case, please give more details about the computer so we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to(as admin): Control Panel -> Device Manager: Choose the Battery tab and deactivate/uninstall all the battary options, but "Microsoft AC Adapter" and "Microsoft Composite Battery".